# NullReferenceException when set value to a property

Tags: c#, .net, exception, inotifypropertychanged

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Cls : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string my;
        public  string MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return my;
            }
            set
            {
                my = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty")); 
            }

        }

        public Cls()
        {
            MyProperty = "Hello";
        }

        public void print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MyProperty);
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cls s = new Cls();
            s.print();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it gives:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

When I do not use `INotifyPropertyChanged` it works fine. I do not understand cause of problem.

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: `MyProperty = "Hello";`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is noone listening to `PropertyChanged`, which will then be null when trying to call it. Use an `OnPropertyChanged` method instead:

```
private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName){
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    // With C# 6 this can be replaced with
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public  string MyProperty
{
    get { return my; }
    set
    {
       if (my == value)
           return;

        my = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
}
```

To avoid it being `null` you have to subscribe to it, for instance from your main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    Cls s = new Cls();
    s.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("MyProperty changed!");
    s.print();
}
```

which is a fancy way of writing

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    Cls s = new Cls();
    s.PropertyChanged += ShowMessage;
    s.print();
}

private void ShowMessage(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args){
    MessageBox.Show("MyProperty changed!");
}
```

Whatever is more clear to you.
You can read more about events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

If nothing has subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` event, firing the event will throw a `NullReferenceException`.  You need to do a null check before firing the event, like this:

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty"));
}
```

Comment: Works fine. But what makes PropertyChanged, non-null.. means how it is null at first time and after that it is non-null

Answer (score 4):

The PropertyChanged delegate has no listeners. You should always check that a delegate isn't null before you raise it.

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyProperty"));
}
```

Also, judging from your code, you probably meant for `OnPropertyChanged` to be called when the property is changed. In order to do so, you should add event listener to `PropertyChanged`, and call `OnPropertyChanged` in the listener. You can do it by adding the following code:

```
//Old ctor
public Cls()
{
    PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Cls_PropertyChanged); //Register the event handler
    MyProperty = "Hello";
}

void Cls_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName); //Call your method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the error in my 'viewmodel' class because i omitted the INotifyPropertyChanged interface declaration.

so from something like this

```
public class viewmodel
   {}
```

to this

```
public class viewmodel: INotifyPropertyChanged
 {}
```

fixed it.

---

Would not have been helpful to the OP but an oversight that someone else might make?